# Verify my website when it is .tk

Tags: domains, google-search-console

I'm trying to verify my website so it appears on google, I think, I'm very new with all this.
However, it doesn't seem to be an option...
My website is host in dropbox and the domain is free.
Is that why I cannot verify?
Have tried the different methods, but nothing.

This is the web: www.angelinajoliemagazines.tk

Comment: Be more specific. What do "doesn't seem to be an option" and "but nothing" mean? Do you even get an indication that verification is pending and then it fails, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to verify your `.tk` domain, as if I recall the free `.tk` domains work by creating a hidden frame containing your website, so still loading your website from your Dropbox (imho an absurd setup idea).

So Google will see you `.tk` domain as a frame loading a website from `dropbox.com`.... which obviously you won't be able to verify. You need to get a proper webhost! There are plenty of free ones out there, at the very least then you'll have  your own subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Just choose to verify by adding a meta tag to your page, add the provided meta tag into your code and you should be good.